# There's a way to install Borland Delphi 7 via command line?

Tags: powershell, delphi, command-line, delphi-7

I am writing a PowerShell script for the development environment setup with Delphi 7 and Delphi Berlin and I have some doubts if it is possible to perform silent installation by going through all steps via command line.

I found some examples of Delphi 2005 and 2007, but they don't work in Delphi 7.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If my memory serves me corectly Delphi 7 documentation actually contains instructions of how to perform a silent install. I'm at work and therefore I don't have Delphi 7 instalation CD at hand to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the Install.Txt file which shipped with D7:

> This product uses the Microsoft Installer (MSI) 2.0
>   service to perform the installation.

The .MSI file is in the same directory as the Install.Txt and is named:

```
Borland Delphi 7.Msi
```

, size 5818880 bytes, which you should be able to invoke from the command line.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: But, what's the correct parameters i need to pass. I tried some args from this [link](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/8/361519.html) and it didn't work :(